# Can one Telegram bot promote and demote another bot to admin?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have two bots in my group, first bot have all available permissions, second bot just a simple group member.

I try to promote to admin second bot with the first by sending

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot67XXXXXXXX:AAFXXXXXXXXXXXXX9w/promoteChatMember?user_id=SECOND_BOT_ID&chat_id=MY_GROUP_ID&can_manage_chat=true
```

and it works, but when I try to demote second bot to simple member by changing `can_manage_chat` to `false`, api return error

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: BOT_CHANNELS_NA"}
```

So, how I can demote my other bot?